# Include 3rd-party Javascript Libraries into an AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm trying to include a javascript libraries (actually, a handfull) into my AngularJS app. So far, I am building a stripped down version of this app, with no design. It's just all about functionality and data processing at this point.

This is the first javascript library I'm attempting to add into my AngularJS app: https://github.com/LarryBattle/Ratio.js

At first, I tried to simply include it into my HTML file using script src tag, but when I try to use it inside my controller, I receive this error: *ReferenceError: require is not defined*

I've read that it's best to convert javascript libraries into services or directives or even filters when using AngularJS. Can anyone provide any insight on the best way to do this? Or perhaps some relevant tutorials? I have not been able to find one that is simple enough to apply to my needs. Can anyone help or provide some direction with this? Here's my code so far:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>PercentCalc App</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

Amount: <input type="number" ng-init="amountone=28" ng-model="amountone"> Value: <input type="number" ng-init="valueone=300" ng-model="valueone">
<br />
Amount: <input type="number" ng-init="amounttwo=3.5" ng-model="amounttwo"> Value: <input type="number" ng-init="valuetwo=50" ng-model="valuetwo">
<br /><br />
=========================
<br /><br />
Test ratio: {{ amountone }}/{{ amounttwo}} = {{ ratioone() }} OR {{ ratioonestring }}<br />
Test ratio: {{ amounttwo }}/{{ amountone}} = {{ ratiotwo() }}<br />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ratio.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/percentcalc-ng-one.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

===

```
//percentcalc-ng-one.js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    console.log($scope);
    var Ratio = require("lb-ratio"); // <--- this is where the error is thrown
    $scope.ratioone = function () { return $scope.amountone / $scope.amounttwo; }
    $scope.ratiotwo = function () { return $scope.amounttwo / $scope.amountone; }

    $scope.ratioonestring = Ratio.parse( $scope.ratioone() ).simplify().toString();

});
```

I would really be appreciative if anyone could help direct me on how to include 3rd-party javascript libraries into my AngularJS app. I'd like to be able to add it as a dependency into certain apps, that way I could reuse this feature in other apps. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comment out `var Ratio = require("lb-ratio")` and it should work.

When you include the script, Ratio is already on your global scope (of the window, not your controller).

Comment: OK great! That definitely helped! I do not receive the error anymore, however, it seems like the library is not able to parse AngularJS variable data. I am receiving output from the Ratio library "NaN" which means "Not a Number". Should I include the Ratio function into my controller scope? How do I do that?

Comment: Are you setting values for $scope.amountone and $scope.amounttwo?  I'm guessing that one, or both of those variables are undefined.

Just for the sake of testing Ratio, try hard coding some values in there and just running it through a browser's dev tools. 

var testRatio = Ratio.parse(2.34563).simplify().toString();

If that was the issue, I suggest taking a day or two and going over Angular's web site.  Their "Tutorial" is very helpful for learning Angular
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: Yes, as you can see in my code, I'm using ng-init to initialize those values, and the other calculations are working fine, just not the value that is supposed to be printed to the screen for the js lib Ratio functionality.

Comment: Sorry.  Reading fail on my part with the init values.  Try removing the ng-init and set the initial values in the controller.  Also, it might have just been a copy and paste mistake but close your input tags "/>"

Comment: I removed the ng-init tags from the input fields and set all of those variable amounts in the controller at the top. This actually rendered the correct Ratios as expected using the javascript library! However, once I started modifying the values in the input fields, the other calculations changed properly and in realtime, but the Ratio library value did not change at all after it was initially rendered to the view. I think I'll have to add this library into a service or something in order for it to be able to update in realtime.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right path.  Good luck.  Would you mind marking the answer correct as it solved your original problem with the require() line throwing errors.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I've created a tool which automatically converts libraries that support RequireJS/Almond into Angular injectables. It's called angular global injector and available on github. Here's the link: https://github.com/btesser/angular-global-injector

Here's what a standard usage would look like.

1)  Include your js sources

```
<!-- jQuery is optional, but if included must be first -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<!-- The next 2 scripts must be loaded in this order -->
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular-global-injector.js"></script>

<!-- Include all of your other dependencies here -->
<script src="lodash.js"></script>
<script src="d3.js"></script>
```

2) Inject dependencies

```
angular
  .module('app', ['globals'])
  .controller('DiController', function DiController($q, _, d3) {
    // The following 2 lines work as expected
    _.map([1,2,3],function (num) { console.log(num); });
    d3.selectAll("p");
  });
console.log(window.d3); // undefined... Accessible only as an angular injectable
console.log(window._); // undefined
```

See here for plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/0hWvNbrHpLO1l7rpvJkZ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var Ratio = require("lb-ratio");
```

this instruction is required only for node.js server files. angularjs files reside on the browser hence you can directly use.

```
Ratio.parse( 12.12121212121212 ).simplify().toString();
```

As VtoCorleone had already mentioned when you did

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ratio.js"></script>
```

the variable Ratio got bound to your global scope and you do not need to do anything special to use it.

Comment: thank you for the insight! I do not receive the error anymore, however, it seems like the library is not able to parse AngularJS variable data. I am receiving output from the Ratio library "NaN" which means "Not a Number". Should I include the Ratio function into my controller scope? How do I do that?

Comment: I think either of $scope.amountone or $scope.amounttwo is string or undefined. can you try console.log($scope.amountone+$scope.amounttwo); in your ratio function

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. The console spits out "NaN" when I added the line you recommended. I'm not sure why it's a string, and I'm not sure why Angular can still process it if it's a string. I guess it changes the variable type automatically? How can I change it?

Comment: try parseInt($scope.amountone) / parseInt($scope.amounttwo)